# Find all lines with keyword and extract number

Tags: linux, bash, grep, text-processing

I would like to find line which starts from word: "ERRORS" and exctract number from that line.

Part of file:

```
...
[ERROR] No keywords and test cases defined in file
File path: libraries_instances.robot

TEST SUITES SUMMARY:
ERRORS:        148
WARNINGS:      89
CS VIOLATIONS: 201
```

My solution is:

```
grep ERRORS .validation.log | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'
```

is it possible to make it better and use only one grep?

Finally I would like to assign that value to variable in my bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `linux` tag is present in question, assuming `GNU grep` with `-P` option is available

```
$ grep -oP 'ERRORS.*\h\K\d+' .validation.log
148
```

- `ERRORS.*\h\K` here the `\K` option helps to mark the starting point of regex.. string matched up to this point won't be part of output
- also note that `man grep` warns about using `-P` as experimental, but I haven't faced any issue so far..  (see https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/pkgreport.cgi?package=grep for known `GNU grep` issues)

Alternate solution using `awk`

```
$ awk '/ERRORS:/ && NF==2{print $NF}' .validation.log
148
```

- `/ERRORS:/ && NF==2` match line containing `ERRORS:` and has only two fields (by default, one or more contiguous whitespace is field delimiter)
- `print $NF` print the last field

Comment: Thanks for your help.